# the improper use of a GetX has been detected

Tags: flutter, error-handling, flutter-getx

Here is my code of TextFormField in which I have used getx to change the obscure value in case of the password field.

[image]

and here is the error I received.

[image]

Here is the complete code

```html
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final String label;
  final String hintText;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final bool isPassword;
  final bool enable;
  final Widget suffixIcon;
  final bool hasSuffix;
  final bool hasPrefix;
  final VoidCallback? suffixIconFunction;
  final Widget prefixIcon;
  final Color themeColor;
  final VoidCallback? prefixIconFunction;
  final String? Function(String?)? function;

  const CustomTextField({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.label,
    required this.hintText,
    required this.keyboardType,
    this.isPassword = false,
    this.enable = true,
    required this.suffixIcon,
    required this.prefixIcon,
    this.suffixIconFunction,
    this.prefixIconFunction,
    this.function,
    this.hasSuffix = true,
    this.hasPrefix = true,
    this.themeColor = KColors.kWhite,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
      return TextFormField(
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        enabled: enable,
        controller: controller,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        cursorColor: themeColor,
        cursorWidth: 2.0,
        cursorHeight: dynamicHeight(.024),
        obscureText: isPassword ? obscureText.value : false,
        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        inputFormatters: [
          keyboardType == TextInputType.phone
              ? FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                  RegExp("[0-9]"),
                )
              : FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                  RegExp("[a-zA-Z  @/:? 0-9 \\- _ .]"),
                ),
          keyboardType == TextInputType.phone
              ? FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
                  RegExp('[\\.|\\,\\-\\_]'),
                )
              : FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
                  RegExp('[\\#]'),
                ),
        ],
        style: TextStyle(
          color: themeColor,
          fontSize: dynamicWidth(.04),
        ),
        validator: function,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          suffixIcon: hasSuffix
              ? InkWell(
                  onTap: isPassword
                      ? () {
                          obscureText.value = !obscureText.value;
                        }
                      : suffixIconFunction,
                  child: suffixIcon,
                )
              : null,
          isDense: true,
          prefixIcon: hasPrefix
              ? InkWell(
                  onTap: prefixIconFunction,
                  child: prefixIcon,
                )
              : null,
          label: Text(label),
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: themeColor),
          hintText: hintText,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: themeColor.withOpacity(.4)),
          disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              dynamicWidth(.04),
            ),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              width: 2,
              color: themeColor,
            ),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              dynamicWidth(.04),
            ),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              width: 2,
              color: themeColor,
            ),
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              dynamicWidth(.04),
            ),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              width: 2,
              color: themeColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Here above is the code of the custom TestFormField so that I can use it dynamically in my project everywhere I want to use it.

Comment: can you please add code of obscureText's value

Comment: @RavinLaheri var obscureText = true.obs;

Comment: @RandalSchwartz well everyone has their own point of view. But I really found getx helpful and easy to implement.

Answer (score 3):

It's happening because when the isPassword is false there's a normal value, not an RX that's why it's throwing an error.

Obx/Get needs at least one RX/Observable value inside.

In your case you can create one default Rx bool like

above return obx

```
    RxBool defaultBool = false.obs;
   return Obx(() {


   ..... Your code
   

   obscureText: isPassword ? obscureText.value : defaultBool.value,


   .... your code
```

Comment: if I change isPassword type from bool to RXBool then it also pops an error of --> The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.

Comment: Please add your text code instead of the Screenshot. I'll send you a solution @HassanGujjar

Comment: check the question again I added my whole code

Comment: Please check updated code @HassanGujjar

Answer (score -1):

You can try to always check for the observed value and not only when `isPassword` is true. Maybe like

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
      bool obscure = obscureText.value;
      return TextFormField(
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        enabled: enable,
        controller: controller,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        cursorColor: themeColor,
        cursorWidth: 2.0,
        cursorHeight: dynamicHeight(.024),
        obscureText: isPassword ? obscure : false,
        ...
```

Comment: no, it again pops an error. The above-given solution is correct. Thanks for your help too